# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint while saving ModelForm

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, database-design, modelform

My views.py

```
class UserProfileFormView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        userform = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='users')
        userprofileform = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='userprofiles')
        if userform.is_valid() and userprofileform.is_valid():
            new_user = userform.save()
            new_userprofile = userprofileform.save(commit=False)
            new_userprofile.user = new_user  
            new_userprofile.save() #### Error is here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:welcome'))
        else:
            userform = UserForm(prefix='users')
            userprofileform = UserProfileForm(prefix='userprofiles')
            return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'user_form': userform, 'userprofile_form': userprofileform})
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        userform = UserForm(prefix='users')
        userprofileform = UserProfileForm(prefix='userprofiles')    
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'user_form': userform, 'userprofile_form': userprofileform})
```

my models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="user details")
    rewardpoints = models.IntegerField("rewardpoints", default=0) 

    def __str__(self):  
          return "%s's profile" % self.user.username
```

my forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['rewardpoints']

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

While submitting the `POST` request, it gives me:

> ```
> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_userprofile_user_id_key"
> DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
> ```

Django-1.7, PostgreSQL 9.3.6.

I have even tried changing the database, running `manage.py flush` but still no luck. Please give me leads.

These are the Postgres tables:

`auth_user`

```
    Column    |           Type           |                       Modifiers                        
--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                  | not null default nextval('auth_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 password     | character varying(128)   | not null
 last_login   | timestamp with time zone | not null
 is_superuser | boolean                  | not null
 username     | character varying(30)    | not null
 first_name   | character varying(30)    | not null
 last_name    | character varying(30)    | not null
 email        | character varying(75)    | not null
 is_staff     | boolean                  | not null
 is_active    | boolean                  | not null
 date_joined  | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "auth_user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "auth_user_username_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username)
    "auth_user_username_615a2337ed0898d6_like" btree (username varchar_pattern_ops)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "account_emailaddress" CONSTRAINT "account_emailaddress_user_id_43dc87ab5814030c_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "auth_user_groups" CONSTRAINT "auth_user_groups_user_id_365abed9418f0260_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "auth_user_user_permissions" CONSTRAINT "auth_user_user_permiss_user_id_50dbc406b985ecc5_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "authtoken_token" CONSTRAINT "authtoken_token_user_id_1496385360418da0_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "django_admin_log" CONSTRAINT "django_admin_log_user_id_1f9a3ebc14adbded_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "users_userprofile" CONSTRAINT "users_userprofile_user_id_35e6cb6eb864c8ec_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

`users_userprofile`

```
  Column      |  Type   |                           Modifiers                            
--------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer | not null default nextval('users_userprofile_id_seq'::regclass)
 rewardpoints | integer | not null
 user_id      | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "users_userprofile_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "users_userprofile_user_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "users_userprofile_user_id_35e6cb6eb864c8ec_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: Can you have a look at the indexes it has created in the database for a clue.  That error seems odd as there is no constraint on using the same user for many profiles, which appears to be what it is complaining about.

Comment: @PhoebeB I have added table schema in EDIT.

Comment: Aside: Why are all your FK constraints `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, while the (cheaper) default is `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE`. Is this on purpose or by accident?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The schema has been generated by Django using the models that I have mentioned. I will look more into the lead provided by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of having a separate table `users_userprofile` is probably to allow multiple entries for a single user.

*(Else, if there can only be a single attribute `rewardpoints` per user, you would just add the column to the table `auth_user` and drop the table `users_userprofile`.)*

The actual implementation contradicts this idea. You have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `users_userprofile.user_id`, which does not make sense:

```
"users_userprofile_user_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id)
```

It causes the error and should probably be removed.

Comment: I want to extend my User table to add more field. The Django documentation states that we can do this like this. But, it is not working out as expected. New to Django and pgsql.

Comment: I am really sorry @Erwin but I was making an embarrassing mistake. Since I was new to Django, I copied some source from some tutorial, and there was a post_save hook which was saving my UserProfile instance upon new creation of User. I have removed it and it is working fine now. Thanks a lot for your response.