# Can't access admin page with PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL database with my new project, I did everything properly in settings module and with migrations but I cannot access my admin page?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Site matching query does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814059/site-matching-query-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every django app needs a `Site` to run, So 
write in django shell

```
 $> ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site()
>>> site.domain = 'example.com'
>>> site.name = 'example.com'
>>> site.save()
```

Comment: Error : "duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089850/integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-django-postgres                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695323/django-db-utils-integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615208/duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-while-saving-modelform                          these link may help you